# phpmyadmin creating ENUM error

Tags: mysql, sql, user-interface, syntax

I use MySQL mariadb- 10.1.9 and phpmyadmin 4.6.4
I used the phpmyadmin GUI interface to create tables and I keep getting this syntax error whenever I try to create a table with an ENUM type field.
like on this picture:
[image]

And the error is:

[image]

I was able to fix this problem by using only sql code to create the table. But I would appreciate if someone can show me how I can fix this with the GUI.

regards.

Comment: Are those curly quotes I see in `'yes','no'`?

Comment: Doesn't the 'as defined' value also need single quotes?

Answer (score 0):

'yes','no' is written in single-quote. And the gui was supposed to put it same. But it was changed to ENUM(0).

Comment: Don't use an `ENUM` for this type of flag. Use a `TINYINT(1)` and set it to 1 or 0. This matches up with how MySQL interprets boolean values, as in `WHERE active` is valid with the `TINYINT` approach, but not with `ENUM`.

Comment: Ok, how about for a field like 'sex'?  I want to enumerate on only fixed value like 'male','female'.

Comment: That's also a misconception. "X" is an allowed option in many countries where that means "Not Applicable" or "Other". Don't lock in things unless it's strictly necessary.